# ooo-thumbnailer doesn't work

Tags: thumbnails

I have Ubuntu 11.10 installed on 3 different PCs and ooo-thumbnailer doesn't work on any of them.

I don't know how to get it work --  I've tried to uninstall and reinstall, I've tried to update it to version 0.3.1, but nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try restarting Nautilus after installing it (but before uninstalling it), for example, by logging out and back in (or rebooting)?

Comment: Hello. I'm the developer of ooo-thumbnailer. It does have a few serious bugs on Ubuntu 11.10. I've fixed them in my code, but this question has given the motivation to release the fixes, and start proposing them to Debian and Ubuntu. Expect an answer tonight (British time) once I've set up a PPA.

Answer (score 4):

Try installing the latest release from the official PPA:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:flimm/ooo-thumbnailer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ooo-thumbnailer
```

The new release will only work with some Microsoft Office files, but it should work with all LibreOffice and OpenOffice.org files. Give it a go and let me know if it works.

Comment: It looks like this PPA is no longer mantained: it doesn't have a «Quantal» _nor_ a «Precise» build.